# Ordering posts by custom field and grouped by month

Tags: wp-query, loop, date

I need display all custom posts (event), order them by custom field (date) and group by month:
September

- Event 1
- Event 2

August

- Event 3

July

- Event 4
- Event 5

I know, it is frequently asked question here, but despite the reading many similar issues, I can't do anything meaningful according them. So all posts are still ordered by default - by date of publishing. I will grateful for any hints. This is my code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'=>'event',
'posts_per_page'=> -1,
'order'=> 'DESC',
'orderby'=> 'meta_value',    
'meta_key'=>'event_start_date'
)

$events = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ($events->have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

the_title();
// (etc.)

endwhile;
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: What is your date format in your custom field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

  $period = date("Y-m-d");

  $args = array(
  'post_type'=>'event',
  'posts_per_page'=> -1,
  'order'=> 'DESC',
  'orderby'=> 'meta_value',    
  'meta_key'=>'event_start_date'
  'meta_value' => $period,


 )

 $events = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ($events->have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

the_title();
// (etc.)

endwhile;
endif; 

?>
```

Please follow below link  for details.

[Link for details](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-custom-date-archive)

[link for code source](http://codeblow.com/questions/wordpress-occasions-arranged-by-month/)

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, something is wrong: "Oops, Post Not Found!"

Comment: please check second link where code example is given.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the links. Thank you. I am going to study :-)